# sudo permission issue LoadModule wsgi_module

Tags: linux, django, apache-http-server, ubuntu

I'm trying to run this command on Ubuntu:

```
echo "LoadModule wsgi_module /usr/lib/apache2/modules/mod_wsgi.so" > /etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load
```

I get a permission issue, normally this can be resolved with added the `sudo` command, however this still gives a permission issues on the `/etc/apache2/mods-available/wsgi.load`.

How do I add sudo to both parts?

Answer (score 1):

You don't; you add `sudo` to the whole thing.

```
sudo sh -c "echo ... > ..."
```